# Python 2D Dynamic List Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python.

```
     for row in reader:

            if (int(row[0]) <= nextWeek):
                  y[i].append(row[1])
            if (int(row[0]) > nextWeek):
                    i = i + 1
                    y[i].append(row[1])
```

These are the parts of the code , here I need to acheive this kind of things in Python , What is the **correct way of declaring y** ?

Here I used **y = [ [ ] ]** , But I need the correct type for **y** something like basically 2D Dynamic List Declaration / Initialization example ?

Comment: If you initialise y as `y = []`, you add stuff with `y.append(row[1])`.  You dont need the `y[i].append(...)` if I understand correctly what you want to do

Comment: I need Y to be the format of y=[ [  ] , [  ] , [  ] ] and then need to access it with y [0] , y [1] , y [3] . But before that all I need to initialize how many list inside should there for accessing like that. That's my issue. without mentioning how many lists inside at first, can't we have any data structure which dynamically increase the lists inside

Comment: @pathoren ? :..

Comment: Will each thing you append (i.e. row[1]) be of the same length?  My guess is that it's a week, so it should always be of length 7, right?

Comment: Here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/BLcfMRc6

Comment: Help me on optimize the code in better way

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is a defaultdict.
Lets say you've got:

```
from collections import defaultdict
y = defaultdict(list)
(...)
for row in reader:
        if (int(row[0]) <= nextWeek):
              y[i].append(row[1])
        if (int(row[0]) > nextWeek):
                i = i + 1
                y[i].append(row[1])
```

In this case, the defaultdict will store the "i" (index) as a key, where the value will be a list by default. (and as such it is easy to extend the list, when not-knowing how many of them should exist).

Comment: If we go with this , then we will be having one element in one list. This is not the case.we need to store 7 elements in a list (a week)

Comment: something like y[0] = [ 2.4 , 3.4 , 2.3 , 2.3 , 1.2 , 1.2 , 4.5 ]

Comment: Well, I dunno what's the problem then. If the "i" is the weekend number, then as long as you keep calling y[i].append(item) all of the items will end up in the same list. ex: y[0].append(3) y[0].append(11) y[0].append(4) y[0] = [3, 11, 4]

And if you want to place the whole list, just use:
y[0].extend(list)

y[0].extend( [ 2.4 , 3.4 , 2.3 , 2.3 , 1.2 , 1.2 , 4.5 ])
y[0] =  [ 2.4 , 3.4 , 2.3 , 2.3 , 1.2 , 1.2 , 4.5 ]